# Maven+Selenium+Jetty - ClassNotFoundException when Jetty is Shutting Down

Tags: maven, selenium, integration-testing, maven-jetty-plugin

I am running an Integration test with Maven, Selenium and Jetty. The tests are executed OK, but when the server are shutting down then the Jetty server throws a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$371`. Here's the complete stack trace:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.main.SeleniumHelloWorldExampleIT
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 13.479 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- selenium-maven-plugin:2.3:stop-server (stop-selenium) @ MySampleWebApp ---
Stopping Selenium server...
00:28:55,976 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Credential] Checking Resource aliases
00:28:55.983 INFO - Command request: shutDownSeleniumServer[, ] on session null
00:28:55.989 INFO - Shutdown command received
00:28:55.992 INFO - Got result: OK on session null
00:28:55.994 INFO - initiating shutdown
Stop request sent
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:stop (stop-jetty) @ MySampleWebApp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.9:verify (verify) @ MySampleWebApp ---
[INFO] Stopping server 0
[INFO] Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: D:\projects\mvn-ckbk-samples\ch-2\test-auto\MySampleWebApp\target\failsafe-reports
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:06.833s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Nov 09 00:28:56 VET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/38M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Shutdown hook executing
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$371
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.createProxy(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.proxy(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.isValidMethod(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:65)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethodInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:2808)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:2800)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getMethodWithCachingInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:1181)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createPojoCallSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3001)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createPojoSite(CallSiteArray.java:114)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.mojo.support.ProcessLauncher$_launch_closure1.doCall(ProcessLauncher.groovy:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:273)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.mojo.support.ProcessLauncher$_launch_closure1.doCall(ProcessLauncher.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:273)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:271)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:354)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Exception in thread "Selenium Server Runner" org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$371
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:95)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:273)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:271)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:354)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$371
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.createProxy(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.proxy(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.isValidMethod(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:65)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethodInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:2808)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:2800)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getMethodWithCachingInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:1181)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createPojoCallSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3001)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createPojoSite(CallSiteArray.java:114)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.mojo.support.ProcessLauncher$_launch_closure1.doCall(ProcessLauncher.groovy:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:273)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.mojo.support.ProcessLauncher$_launch_closure1.doCall(ProcessLauncher.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    ... 7 more
[INFO] Shutdown hook complete

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any idea why is this happening?

The POM I am using:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MySampleWebApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MySampleWebApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MySampleWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.37.1</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>MySampleWebApp</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-selenium</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start-server</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <background>true</background>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-selenium</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop-server</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.26</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>8005</stopPort>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Failsafe for integration testing -->
            <!-- This ensures that post-integration tests are run even if testing fails -->
            <!-- Integration tests are *IT.java by default -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a stopWait to the jetty configuration :

```
<configuration>
  <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
  <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
  <stopPort>8005</stopPort>

  <stopWait>5</stopWait>

</configuration>
```

This ensures jetty stops before the next maven goal is executed and importantly before the build completes.

It's this case where Jetty is attempting shutdown when the Maven build has completed that you will see this ClassNotFoundError.

See also http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-stop-goal

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work either with the `stopWait`.

Comment: Maybe my computer is too slow, I change `<stopWait>5</stopWait>` to `<stopWait>10</stopWait>` and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like groovy runtime dependency missing. Please refer http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Groovy+Runtime

Comment: But its caused by Exception in thread "Shutdown" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspApplicationContextImpl, How can that be fixed?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about your answer? I added the dependencies of the article but makes nothing, still receiving the same response when Jetty is shutting down.

Comment: Will you please share your pom file

Comment: @user861594 I managed to remove the `ClassNotFoundException` of the `jasper.runtime` by using this dependency `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
       </dependency>`. Now the exception is shorter and remains the `ClassNotFoundException` of the `groovy.runtime.dmg`, which I tested by including all those dependencies in the article and none of them work. In fact, looks like the dependency is not from Groovy itself but a resource used by Groovy, it can be seen by the `$371` at the end.

Comment: @TechCrunch, No, I could not solve it. I finally ended up using **Arquillian for the Integration-Tests**, it works good and does not throw any exception during nor after the execution of the tests. Follow this tutorial: [Arquillian Get-Started](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, adding this dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
          </dependency>
```